# Determine whether the given file path string is remote or local

Tags: java, file, filepath

I want to determine whether the given file path string is remote or local.

I have looked at few java examples which suggest to use the below

1. fileStore api which is available in jdk7 but am using jdk6
2. Determine using regular expressions by searching for "www" or "http".

Could you please let me know if there is any better way of solving this.?

LocalFilePath:

c:/dir1/dir2/file.xml

RemoteFilePath:

https:///dir1/dir2/file.xml

To be more specific, Given the DNSName , Is it possible to figure out if the file.xml is in remote or local machine. I am aware that we can figure it out using HostName(Ex:Saturn) by INetAddress.
Can you please let me know if we can determine it using DNS Name(Ex: Saturn.rev.com)?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you would consider a local vs a remove file?

Comment: What if the path is a symbolic link to a network filesystem? Ore are you just trying to tell the difference between HTTP URLs (which might be local, of course, e.g. `http://localhost/` ) and file URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the file with an instance of java.io.File, and then if not throws an exception is a local file.

Comment: This is not correct--unless you consider 'local' to include mapped drives, etc.  (not your problem, the question given is vague as to what's local or not.)

Comment: Also depends on whether the file is expected to actually exist yet - which isn't specified in the question. Permissions may also be a problem.

Comment: Yeah.  The vagueness has me making the incredibly wild assumption that anything that can be accessed via file:/// qualifies as 'local.'  I think the asker is going to be more or less tied to the standard of looking up file:/// url:, ftp:, etc. all the common pre-path signals and doing his matching based on that.

Comment: There are many possibilities, but if @Michael Maze is not taking in count even a few of them, I think my answer will accomplish what he's looking for.

Comment: @Federico Thank you for your answer and apologies for asking vague question. I have edited my question now. Could you please let me know if we can determine if host is remote or local using DNS name.

Comment: Hi Michael, from what I understand you have two types of paths. I think you can distinguish them with pattern matching. Take in count what kind of paths you will have to process, and also the comments of  user1701047 and DNA, there also other posibilities that you may take in count(or maybe not, and with some string checks you're alright)

Comment: Not a fan of the try, pray, catch, fail method.